# THREE.js loading the same animated GLB in a loop only plays the last loaded model

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to load a swarm of animated butterflies in a loop, for some reason only one of them, either the first or the last actually plays, I presume it's because I need to clone the gltf.scene but there is a known bug with cloning animated gltfs.

Any help appreciated.

```
let mixer = [];
    const butt_loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    for(var i=0;i<40;i++){
    butt_loader.load('butterfly_rigged.glb', function (gltf) {
    var butt_scale = 1;

        var model = gltf.scene;
        model.position.z = -3 - Math.random()*7;
        model.position.x = 6*Math.random();
        model.position.y = 6*Math.random();
        model.scale.x = butt_scale*Math.random();
        model.scale.y = butt_scale*Math.random();
        model.scale.z = butt_scale*Math.random();

        model.rotation.y = -Math.PI/4;
        model.rotation.z = 0.1;
        model.rotation.x = Math.PI/4;
        butt_scene.add(model.clone());

        mixer.push(new THREE.AnimationMixer(model));
        gltf.animations.forEach((clip) => {
        mixer[mixer.length-1].clipAction(clip).play();
        }); 
    });
    }
    var butt_clock = new THREE.Clock();
    function render_butt(){
    for(var i=0;i<mixer.length;i++){
        if(mixer[i]!=null) mixer[i].update(butt_clock.getDelta());
    }
    requestAnimationFrame( render_butt );   
    butt_ren.clear();
    butt_ren.render( butt_scene, butt_camera );
    }
    render_butt();
```

Comment: [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-game.html) clones a bunch of skinned animated characters and animates them.

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
    for(var i=0;i<mixer.length;i++){
        if(mixer[i]!=null) mixer[i].update(butt_clock.getDelta());
    }
```

better to replace with this:

```
    var delta = butt_clock.getDelta();
    for(var i=0;i<mixer.length;i++){
        if(mixer[i]!=null) mixer[i].update(delta);
    }
```

`.getDelta()` gets delta since last call of it, so when you call it in the loop, all delta will be `0`, except for the first iteration. When you put it off of the loop, then you'll get it once and pass the same (non-zero) value to all mixers.

Comment: I get this error then:

three.js:24759 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'frame' of undefined
    at projectObject (three.js:24759)
    at projectObject (three.js:24813)
    at projectObject (three.js:24813)
    at projectObject (three.js:24813)
    at WebGLRenderer.render (three.js:24585)
    at render_butt (index.html:597)

Comment: @BinkyNichols then it's better to provide an editable working live code example. (code snippet, jsfiddle, codepen etc.)